# Sorting feedback results by url with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem sorting my results with MySQL. I'm building a feedback function that sends good, average or poor into my database. I made a page in order to check those results and sort them by url. It works fine except that it shows me the total number of each feedback when I want it to show me the total for each page distinctively.

For example I got this :

URL 1 : Good 10 | Average 2 | Poor 4

URL 2 : Good 10 | Average 2 | Poor 4

When I want something like this :

URL 1 : Good 6 | Average 1 | Poor 0

URL 2 : Good 4 | Average 1 | Poor 4

Here's my code :

```
<?php

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lexcelera', 'root', '');
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT avis, url FROM feedback');

while ($donnees = $sorter->fetch()) {

?>

<table><tr><td style="width:500px;">

<?php      
    echo $donnees['url'];
?>

</td>
<td>Good <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo $donnees[0];
}
?>

</td>
<td>Average <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Average\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo $donnees[0];
}
?>

</td>
<td>Poor <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Poor\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo $donnees[0];
}
?>

</td></tr>
</table>

<?php
}
$reponse->closeCursor();

?>
```

Any idea of I should do it? I looked a lot on forums but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem...

Thanks!

So now I have this :

```
<?php

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lexcelera', 'root', '');
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT url FROM feedback ORDER BY url');

while ($donnees = $sorter->fetch()) {

?>

<table><tr><td style="width:500px;">

<?php      
    echo "<br/>".$donnees['url'];
?>

</td>
<td>Good <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$donnees[0];
}
?>

</td>
<td>Average <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Average\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$donnees[0];
}
?>

</td>
<td>Poor <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Poor\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$donnees[0];
}
?>

</td></tr>
</table>

<?php

}
$sorter->closeCursor();
?>
```

And it's almost working but it just returns the good statement (stay on 0 for poor and average).

Also I'm not sure about the closure statement : should I put ^response or $sorter?

Comment: Use the SQL 'GROUP BY' function.

Comment: You either filter the data with an url value, or you GROUP it. The COUNT is an aggregate function which works on all rows filtered of a single group. Please read some SQL tutorials, as this is really basic stuff.

Comment: I tried the GROUP BY function but it's not working the way I want... And yes I read a lot of tutorials but can't figure this one out. If I don't use the COUNT, I don't get the value of each feedback anymore ("good good good" instead of "3" for example)...

Comment: Then you're not building your SQL query correctly. Can you post us your group-by query?

Comment: I tried this :
`$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(avis), url FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Average\' GROUP BY url');`

Comment: what result you got then?

Comment: I have for each url : Good 211034011612 | Average 51341 | Poor 871750.

When I don't use the GROUP BY function I got this : Good 166 | average 86 | Poor 154 which are the total number of times each feedback has been sent.

Comment: Are you sure that is the result when you run the query directly on your database? Because you'll have to edit your code if you use the group by query, the logic is different. Your group by query seems correctly.

Comment: Ok on my database its seems to work: I got the coutn of each feedback for each url with `SELECT COUNT(avis), url FROM feedback WHERE avis = 'Poor' GROUP BY url`. So how can I write it properly?

Comment: Maybe  the problem comes from this `$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT avis, url FROM feedback');`? The thing is that it should returns a tab with for each row the url and its numbers of votes for each feedback (good, average and poor). Since I put all the feedback functions inside the loop `while ($donnees = $sorter->fetch()) { }` the problem might come from here?

Comment: Try this query: `$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' $donnees['url'] \'');`

Comment: it returns "unexpected '$donnees' (T_VARIABLE)" :/

Comment: Sorry, it had to be this: `$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');`

Comment: I wrote it like this : `url = \''. $donnees['url'] . '\' ` and it's almost working! (it only works for the good feedbacks). Almost there^^

Edit: ok you also corrected it ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59930/discussion-between-gudgip-and-user3883820).

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return count of all the results having avis='Good',both of URL1 and URL2

Change this to

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' GROUP BY url');
```

Insert a line break

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM test WHERE avis = \'Good\' and url=\''.$donnees['url'].'\'');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$donnees[0];
}
```

Also Change

```
$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT avis, url FROM test group by url');
```

Comment: If you use it like this you need to know the URL already.. why not use a group by function?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing about the url is that I want to sort them according to the page where the feedback is send (there are more than two pages and I don't know in advance their url). So what should I put for the url?

@Gudgip  Yes I tried the group by function but I couldn't find the proper way to sort them the way I want... Any idea?

Comment: @user3883820 How do you want to sort them?

Comment: I want for each url the number of votes. For example there were 4 good feedbacks from url 1, 2 average feedbacks from url 2, etc...

Comment: What result you got when used Group By as above?

Comment: I posted it on the comment above!

Comment: Insert a line break. That solves the issue. Check updated answer:)

Comment: thank you but I still got the total results for each url >< As I stated on the comment above mybe the problem comes from my `$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT avis, url FROM feedback');

while ($donnees = $sorter->fetch()) { }` function since I out eerything inside the loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59924/discussion-between-arunrc-and-user3883820).

Comment: Glad to know that:) Please accept this as answer, if you got result.:)

Comment: Well I mixed solutions from both you and @Gudgipso how should I do? :o I posted the final version though.

Comment: its ok, then 50-50 ;)

Do an upvote for both solutions

Answer (score 1):

Your query need to know which url it has to be. For example:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');
```

There are of course better ways like @arunrc suggested with GROUP BY, but that requires bigger changes.

Also, you are overwriting `$donnees` everytime. Create a new variable for your 'Good' and 'average' and 'poor' results.

And for your last question: the closure. You need to call that on $bdd.

```
$bdd->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working now! However i got an error with `$bdd->closeCursor();` so I changed it back to `$sorter->closeCursor();` and it's okay :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. If my answer is the solution for your problem, then please accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: Well I mixed solutions from both you and @arunc so how should I do? :o

I posted the final version though.

Comment: See which solution helped you most :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
<?php

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lexcelera', 'root', '');
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

$sorter = $bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT url FROM feedback GROUP BY url');

while ($donnees = $sorter->fetch()) {

?>

<table><tr><td style="width:500px;">

<?php      
    echo "<br/>".$donnees['url'];
?>

</td>
<td>Good <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($isGood = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$isGood[0];
}

?>

</td>
<td>Average <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Average\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($isAv = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$isAv[0];
}

?>

</td>
<td>Poor <br />

<?php
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Poor\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($isPoor = $reponse->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$isPoor[0];
}

?>

</td></tr>
</table>

<?php

}
$sorter->closeCursor();
?>
```